# Rails Admin With Dragonfly - Edit. No file present

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin, dragonfly-gem

Using [Rails Admin](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin) with [Dragonfly](https://github.com/markevans/dragonfly). However when I have created a new post with an attachment connected `:ob` to dragonfly and wants to edit it. It sais "No file chosen". As it doesn't pick up that there is already a file present?

In my rails_admin I have done this.

```
edit do
  field :name
  field :information
  field :ob, :dragonfly
  field :document_categories
end
```

Here's my model:

```
class Document < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :document_categories


  after_commit :generate_versions, on: :create
  dragonfly_accessor :ob


  validates :name, :ob, presence: true

  def generate_versions
    DocumentWorker.perform_async(self.id)
  end

  def convertable_image?
    unless self.try(:ob).nil?
      self.try(:ob).mime_type.include?("image") || self.try(:ob).mime_type.include?("pdf")
    else
      return false
    end
  end

  def respond_with_type
    case self.try(:ob).mime_type.split("/")[1]
      when "vnd.ms-powerpoint" , "vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.template"
        "powerpoint"
      when "application/vnd.ms-excel" , "vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
        "excel"       
      when "application/msword" , "vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"
        "word"                
      else
        self.try(:ob).mime_type.split("/")[1]
      end
  end  
  default_scope{order("name ASC")}
end
```

Here's my schema:

```
create_table "documents", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "ob"
    t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
    t.string   "ob_uid"
    t.string   "ob_name"
    t.text     "information"
  end
```

Is there anything else that I need to do in order for it to pick up the file?

https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin

https://github.com/markevans/dragonfly

Comment: Could you show the model and schema that uses Dragonfly and is this a custom view?

Comment: @SacWebDeveloper done! No it's not a custome view.

Comment: Can you also post the `form` present in view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to reproduce your issue using the configuration you provided and the fix that worked for me turned out to be incredibly simple: just **remove the `ob` column from the `documents` table**.

**Explanation:** by default, Dragonfly stores the attached documents on disk (in a file store) to the directory specified in the [Dragonfly initializer](http://markevans.github.io/dragonfly/rails/#setup). In the database, Dragonfly stores **only the name and UID of the documents**. In your case it's the `ob_uid` and `ob_name` columns that you correctly added to your schema.

So, unless you configured some [custom store](http://markevans.github.io/dragonfly/data-stores/) for the documents, I assume you use the default file store and the `ob` column is not needed. In fact, it confuses the `rails_admin`'s [dragonfly support code](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/blob/master/lib/rails_admin/config/fields/types/dragonfly.rb) in such a way that, indeed, the edit page incorrectly show "No file chosen" all the time.

Adding an image after the fix (for simplicity, I removed the `document_categories` association from both the model and the edit action in rails_admin):

[image: Adding an image after the fix]

Comment: "The BountyHunter"

Comment: @Brad, I know, I just couldn't resist this one. But I'll back off for a few days now :)

Comment: Please don't, on my account - I think it's awesome! You're helping a lot of people with some tough questions.

Comment: No no, I'll be just almost off the internet for a while... And thanks!